# How to make dictionaries iterate faster

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I wrote this code but it is very slow. Is there a way to make my code execute faster?

mirTable has 8789 rows and tgtTable has 9100 rows. It's taking 5 minutes to execute this code

```
    mirTable = mirTable.to_dict()
    tgtTable = tgtTable.to_dict()
    for mn in range(mLen):
        m = 0
        for lk in range(tLen):
            g = ""
            h = ""
            if mirTable['UPDATE_KEY'][mn] != tgtTable['UPDATE_KEY'][lk]:
                m = 9
                if row.INTERFACE_KEY == None:
                    g = str(mirTable['CONTACT_SRC_ID'][mn])
                else:
                    g = row.INTERFACE_KEY
                    g = str(mirTable[g][mn])
                if row.INTERFACE_KEY_2 != None:
                    c = row.INTERFACE_KEY_2
                    h = "_" + str(mirTable[c][mn])
                else:
                    h = None
                a = ""
                if row.INTERFACE_KEY_2 == None:
                    a = "drft_" + g + "_" + row.INTERFACE_TYPE + "_" + str(curDate) + ".xml"

                else:
                    a = "drft_" + g + h + "_" + row.INTERFACE_TYPE + "_" + str(curDate) + ".xml"

        if m == 9:

            f.append({i:mirTable[i][mn] for i in (mirTable.keys())})
            p.append(mirTable['UPDATE_KEY'][mn])
            xml_FileName.append(a)
    t1 = time.time()
    print(t1-t0)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow specializes in not-working code. If your code is working correctly, you might submit it at [codereview.se], which handles performance, as well as [style, correctness, security, and a whole lot more](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @usr2564301 Requests for improving code are on-topic at Stack Overflow so long as the request is specific and objectively answerable.